# Is it possible to generate db.changelog-master.yaml on the basis of exsisting database?

Tags: database, heroku, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, liquibase

I would like to use db.changelog-master.yaml file to specify a database on Heroku. I created a relational database thanks to Spring Data JPA and I want to create db.changelog-master.yaml with the same structure as the relational database.

Is there any way to generate the inside of db.changelog-master.yaml (liquidbase) on the basis of exsisting database?

**(Update) Example solution for Postgres:**

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=C:\Users\admin\postgresql-42.2.4.jar --changeLogFile=C:\Users\admin\db.changelog-master.yaml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database" --username=postgres --password=postgres generateChangeLog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the change log to create the existing database schema.

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
      --classpath=\path\to\classes:jdbcdriver.jar \
      --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
      --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" \
      --username=scott \
      --password=tiger \
      generateChangeLog
```

insert your values

Look in official documentation:
https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply ; ) Where I should put this code?

Comment: @plkpiotr Liquibase This is command_line command. You should run this in heroku command-line interface (CLI), I assume. But don't forget to put **your values** to this command parameters.

Comment: Thank you once again! I will try to do this tonight : )